# Indesign get Colors from selected object?

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign

I searched through stackoverflow and the adobe community to find an answer for this. I can't figure out, how to get the color of the selected Object in Indesign.

I know now that I need to check for it to be a swatch or a normal color added. But I just don't know how to then get the color seperated in CMYK out of it for each case.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need 'the' CMYK value of a selected object? Not all swatches are CMYK or can be converted to this (mixed inks, spot colors, gradients).

Comment: The Colors we are using are always CMYK. It's for an intern project and we only use CMYK :) One question though, can you get the start and stop color of a gradient in CMYK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fillColor` of an object is always reported as a [`Swatch`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Swatch.html), even if it's not in the Swatches list. The first test to perform is if it is a `Color`; you can use `instanceof` or `hasOwnProperty` for that. A next sane test is if the color space is CMYK.

A [`Gradient`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Gradient.html), as asked in the comment, is slightly more complicated. It contains a list of `gradientStops`, and each one has a `stopColor` (a simple color or a mixedink) and a location. If it's a simple color, you can retrieve its value as with a plain fill.

```
if (app.documents.length && app.selection.length >= 1 && app.selection[0].hasOwnProperty('fillColor'))
{
    swatch = app.selection[0].fillColor;
    if (swatch instanceof Color &&
        swatch.space == ColorSpace.CMYK)
        alert ("color: "+swatch.colorValue.join(','));
    else if (swatch instanceof Gradient)
    {
        list = [];
        for (i=0; i<swatch.gradientStops.length; i++)
            if (swatch.gradientStops[i].stopColor instanceof Color)
                list.push (i+' = '+swatch.gradientStops[i].stopColor.colorValue.join(','));
            else
                list.push (i+' = ?');
        alert ("gradient:\r"+list.join('\r'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I am doing something wrong, but does this work with text areas?

Comment: Sure it does; I just tried. Do your text areas typically have a CMYK fill? Note that the script is rigged to *not* do anything if (a) you don't have any documents open, (b) not have anything selected, (c) the selection does not have a fill color, and/or (d) this fill color is not CMYK.

Comment: Ah, I think I used the wrong words here. I don't mean the text-frames itself, I mean the text inside

Comment: Well, it also works -- but only when you select a single character! .. I just adjusted the script to additionally allow a selection *longer* than '1' (character/object) but do note that still only the first one is reported. That is, it will not show 'the' CMYK values for a mix of characters or objects.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. I forgot that every single character can have different colors.Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind sharing a good documentation about this topic? In the indesign javascript tutorial there is not much about this... I would be so grateful!

Comment: Alas. Other than those Getting Started documents, Adobe does not provide such a thing; and on my end, it's all experience, as I have been writing Javascripts for InDesign for over a decade now.

Comment: But how did you learn it then? I mean how did you learn for example how to get a color, if you don't even have a documentation about it?

Comment: Sorry, this is getting a bit too chatty for my taste ... But see http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html. Adobe also has a bit more than *just* the Get Started Guide.

Comment: Hey, I didn't talk about the getting started guide, I'm through the actual javascript guide :P But thank you for your time!